# unresolved symbol from libCrunG3.so.1 while loading library from java on solaris

Tags: java, c++, c++11

I have a small example where a c++ library built with -std=c++11 gives unresolved symbol while loading from a java program. 
The version of cc and CC is /opt/developerstudio12.6
The version of java is 1.8.0_151

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

hello.c

```
int example(void)
{
return 99;
}
```

test.java

```
class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {          
    }

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello");
    }
}
```

%/opt/developerstudio12.6/bin/cc -m64 -xarch=sparc -O -xcheck=%none -xcode=pic32 -c hello.c

%/opt/developerstudio12.6/bin/CC -std=c++11 -m64 -xarch=sparc -G hello.o -o libhello.so

%javac test.java

%javah -jni test

%setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH .

%java test

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   libhello.so: ld.so.1: java: fatal: relocation error: file
>   /usr/lib/64/libCrunG3.so.1: symbol _ZTVSt13bad_exception: referenced
>   symbol not found
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
>           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
>           at test.(test.java:9)

Comment: Your native method is named `print` but in C it is `example`, is that correct? Also, the return types are different.

Comment: I removed the print method. it is not used anyway.